# Verbose debug output with pandas Series

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a Pandas Series with 76 elements, when I try to print out the Series (for debugging) it is abbreviated with "..." in the output. Is there a way to pretty print all of the elements of the Series?

In this example, the Series is called "data"

```
print str(data)
```

gives me this

```
Open               40.4568
High               40.4568
Low                 39.806
Close               40.114
Volume            796146.2
Active                   1
TP1_ema                700
stop_ema_width         0.5
LS_ema                  10
stop_window            210
target_width             3
LS_width                 0
TP1_pct                  1
TP1_width                4
stop_ema              1400
...
ValueSharesHeld       NaN
AccountIsWorth        NaN
Profit                NaN
BuyPrice              NaN
SellPrice             NaN
ShortPrice            NaN
BtcPrice              NaN
LongStopPrice         NaN
ShortStopPrice        NaN
LongTargetPrice       NaN
ShortTargetPrice      NaN
LTP1_Price            NaN
STP1_Price            NaN
TradeOpenPrice        NaN
TheEnd              False
Name: 2000-11-03 14:00, Length: 76, dtype: object
```

Note the "..." inserted in the middle. I'm debugging using PTVS on Visual Studio 2013 (Python Tools for Visual Studio". I get the same behaviour with enthought canopy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pd.options.display.max_rows = 100
```

The default is set at 60 (so dataframes or series with more elements will be truncated when printed).

Comment: Fantastic! I had no idea these options existed. Thank you !

Comment: See here for an overview: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#working-with-package-options